# wrapfig followed by a list: items after the first does not wrap around correctly

Tags: floats, lists, itemize

When using the `wrapfig` environment followed by a list, the text of the first item of the list wraps around the figure. So, with the `wrapfig` that has a left placement, this text starts on the right of the figure and, when the figure ends, start from the beginning of the page.

But the text of the second item of the list has a big left margin from the page like the figure is still there (when it's not). How to make the following elements of the list starts from the left edge of the page?

The wrapfig documentation forbids to put the wrapfig environment "immediately" after or before a list environment, but here there's a paragraph and some text in between (so it's not immediately)

The same documentation even says that it's ok for `wrapfig` to *follow* a list environment if there's a newline (`\par`) between the two.

But nothing is said about `wrapfig` *followed by* a list, as this is the case (other than to forbid immediately followed by)

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % for blindtext and example-image-a in example
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

List:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Pic of the behaviour**:

[image]

Comment: There is also the undocumented \WFclear command which can be use to terminate a confused wrapfig.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve your problem splitting the list in two and using the `resume*` option of the `enumitem` package (the second list uses the same parameters as the first list). A small vertical correction is managed by the `before=` key. Don't forget to insert a blank line between the two parts of the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % for blindtext and example-image-a in example
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

List:
\begin{itemize}
  \item A first short item
  \item A second short item
  \item \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[resume, before = \vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax}]
  \item \blindtext
  \item \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understood now. My figure is at the end of the page, and the white space around it is very wide and gets into the following page too. So at the beginning of the following page there is still some space from the figure of the previous page. So I have to guess correctly the exact last item of the previous list for your solution to work. Isn't there a solution that doesn't require to guess the exact last item that gets wrapped aound? Also because it can change if new text is added, without having to declare a list for every item

Comment: Not sure it works, but I had a solution for a similar problem, replacing the `wrapfig` package with the plain TeX `insbox` macro package. It works relatively easily in the neighbourhood of lists, but requires to insert the figure in a minipage if you want to have a caption. I could try to look if it works in your context.

Comment: I solved it with your method. Don't foresee to add text there anyway. If you could try, better. Thanks for the answer (I don't have enough reputation to vote you up)

Comment: @Bernard please suggest from where should I download the insbox macro package, if possible, can you send the link for it, thanks...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Here is a link to [insbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/insbox). However the simplest is to install it through the package manager of  your distribution. Is it TeX Live, MacTeX or MiKTeX?

Comment: This is what I get, notice the short spacing between the second bullet and the line above it, which is where the `resume` kicks in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CUw9.jpg. Acceptable to me.