# Wrapfigure left alignment is not working

Tags: itemize, mactex, wrapfigure

[image]

Code is below:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Project Name:} Task name in Jira. This field has hyperlink on it. When clicked the task name, it redirect you to task page in Jira. 
\item \textbf{Estimated Time:} When project manager assign a task to a team member, he/she should define how many hours this task will be finished. That is estimated time.
\end{itemize}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{zeoCloqLoginPanel}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Time Spent:} This is the answer of how many hours user logged this task.
\item \textbf{Status:} Status in a workflow. It can be To-do/In Progress/In Review/Ready/Sent/Done.
\item \textbf{Due Date:} Answer of when task has to be finished.
\end{itemize}
```

I am new to Latex and using MaCTeX. What I want to do with the code above is to put an image after Estimated Time and I want to go on writing from right of new added image. But I can't figure it out. Could you help me?

edit(Minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=0.50in, bottom=0.98in, left=1.57in, right=0.98in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/caglar/Desktop/} }
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
%PREAMBLE:
\author{ ------------------------------------------------------\\Furkan Caglar Gulmez / 21527027 \\Class: 3rd}
\title{\textbf{Hacettepe University\\ Department \\Of \\Computer Science\\}}
\date{August \nth{6} - September \nth{18}, 2018 (20 workday)\\ ------------------------------------------------------\\  \textbf{ZEO Agency} \\ Bilkent Cyberpark Teknoloji Gelistirme Merkezi, 1606. Cad. Cyberplaza B Blok, No: 401 06800 Cankaya, Ankara}


%CONTENT:
\begin{document}


% 1st PAGE
\maketitle % prints preamble onto pdf

% INTERNSHIP 
\chapter{INTERNSHIP}

%Internship Introduction
\section{Introduction}
First of all, my company doing project time tracking in every project they are working on. 
And they provide their needs with tools called \href{https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira}{Jira} and \href{https://www.timedoctor.com/tr/}{TimeDoctor}. 
But it is costly for the company so that we decided to make an application similar to this. 
Therefore, my task in this company is creating a desktop application which is equivalent to TimeDoctor.
%Internship Steps
\section{Internship Steps}
%Learning Jira's & TimeDoctor's Working Principle
\subsection{Learning Jira's  and TimeDoctor's Working Principle}
To learn Jira's working principle, Firstly, I should get used to Jira so I used it a few days. Meanwhile I search a lot about Jira Rest Api and TimeDoctor.
%Which language to use
\subsection{Choosing Which Language Should I Use}
I had limited time to create the application. Therefore, I chose Java. My main reasons for choosing Java was that it is designed to be easy to use and is therefore easy to write, compile, debug and also Java is object-oriented.This allows me to create modular program and reusable code.
%Start With UI Design
\subsection{Start With UI Design}
Firstly, I started to writing with UI Design. I used Java Swing to design it.
\\
%LOGIN PAGE SCREENSHOT
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{zeoCloqLoginPanel}
\end{wrapfigure}
I started with login page design, It contains two input field for username and password, one checkbox for remember me, three button for different duties.
% Remember me checkbox
\begin{itemize}
\item If remember me button is selected, It holds username and hashed password somewhere in computer. When user wants to login again, input fields will filled automatically.
\end{itemize}
% Change Base URL Button
\begin{itemize}
\item Change Base URL button has a frame which contains an input field and a button named change. Later, my company's base url may change, In this case the program would become unusable so that I fixed that problem with this way.
\end{itemize}
% Change Project name to get current sprint
\begin{itemize}
\item Change project name to get current sprint button has a frame which contains one input field and one button named change. Like base url's probability of change, project which holds active sprint may change later so I fixed it too.
\end{itemize}

% Login Button
\begin{itemize}
\item And Login Button brings main frame which contains projects, a lot of buttons and lots of explanations.
\end{itemize}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{zeoCloqMainPanel}
\end{wrapfigure}

When login button pressed, program creates three api request to Jira.
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{1st:} To get a project name id which contains active sprint
\item \textbf{2nd:} To get active sprint id with project name id which is found in 1st request
\item \textbf{3rd:} To get tasks which belongs loginned user and which is in active sprint that found in 2nd request
\end{itemize}
All of this done, program parses Json Data which returned from 3rd request and creates task panel for each task and add each task panel to general task panel which has scroll property.
\textbf{Task Panel's Properties:}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Project Name:} Task name in Jira. This field has hyperlink on it. When clicked the task name, it redirect you to task page in Jira. 
\item \textbf{Estimated Time:} When project manager assign a task to a team member, he/she should define how many hours this task will be finished. That is estimated time.
\end{itemize}

\begin{wrapfigure}[20]{l}{0.40\textwidth}
\vspace{-120pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{zeoCloqLoginPanel}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Time Spent:} This is the answer of how many hours user logged this task.
\item \textbf{Status:} Status in a workflow. It can be To-do/In Progress/In Review/Ready/Sent/Done.
\item \textbf{Due Date:} Answer of when task has to be finished.
\end{itemize}





\end{document}
```

edit2:
https://imgur.com/LBVLVJ0 - zeoCloqLoginPanel.png
https://imgur.com/7Qf1UG7 - zeoCloqMainPanel.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: I've edited the post, added what you want

Comment: When compiling your example I get a completely different error, something about a missing item. So probably you run LaTeX in a way that ignores all errors which may always give wrong output…

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285756/wrapfig-followed-by-a-list-items-after-the-first-does-not-wrap-around-correctly?s=6|31.9826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use *wrapfigure*. Instead use *tcolorbox* package It is much more flexible.

(second edition with image scaled)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[]{graphicx} 
    \begin{document}
    \tcbset{sidebyside,
      size=minimal,
      width=\textwidth, % total width
      colback=white,
      lower separated=false, % no visible separation
      halign lower=flush left, % right side
      frame empty, % no borders
      sidebyside align=top seam, % vertical alignement of the 2 sides
      lefthand ratio=0.25, % width ratio of the left side
    }
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Project Name:} Task name in Jira. This field has hyperlink on it. When clicked the task name, it redirect you to task page in Jira. 
    \item \textbf{Estimated Time:} When project manager assign a task to a team member, he/she should define how many hours this task will be finished. That is estimated time.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
      \includegraphics{Panel.png}
      \tcblower % left right separation
      \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Time Spent:} This is the answer of how many hours user logged this task.
    \item \textbf{Status:} Status in a workflow. It can be To-do/In Progress/In Review/Ready/Sent/Done.
    \item \textbf{Due Date:} Answer of when task has to be finished.
    \end{itemize}

    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{2cm} %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[lefthand ratio=0.4] % to enlarge the left side
      \includegraphics[scale=2]{Panel.png}
      \tcblower % left right separation
      \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Time Spent:} This is the answer of how many hours user logged this task.
    \item \textbf{Status:} Status in a workflow. It can be To-do/In Progress/In Review/Ready/Sent/Done.
    \item \textbf{Due Date:} Answer of when task has to be finished.
    \end{itemize}

    \end{tcolorbox}


    %

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems so good, but now i couldn't resize image

Comment: What's wrong ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: I have reedited my answer to add a resized image. Is that what you meaned?

Comment: I am so grateful for your effort, It is working thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

not a very good answer but adding a space(\ ) before second begin{itemize} does the trick, (also comment out the vspace)

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.35\textwidth}
%\vspace{-120pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{filename}
\end{wrapfigure}


\  % change here slash space
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Time Spent:} This is the answer of how many hours user logged this task.
\item \textbf{Status:} Status in a workflow. It can be To-do/In Progress/In Review/Ready/Sent/Done.
\item \textbf{Due Date:} Answer of when task has to be finished.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Did you added space after slash

Comment: yes, after slash i added a space

Comment: Can you post the updated code

Comment: It seems you added  negative vspace in itemize after slash, which was not their in example, that may be reason

Comment: Hafid Boukhoulda's solution is the best for me now, thank you so much