# Ghost images when using wrapfig

Tags: wrapfigure, wrapfig

I am having a hard time sometimes getting wrapfig to work and I don't know what the problem is. I stripped an example down to show you one such effect. In this example you will see ghost image placements in the paragraphs below the actual image. I can avoid them in this example by moving the wrapfig further down, the other way to fix it in this example is to delete the \hspace{16pt}. In the stripped down example it was easy to fix but in other cases in my actual document I found it almost impossible to sort out. My question is what tips do people have to avoid issues with wrapfig and what is the cause?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\textbf{Aim:}

\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{0.34\linewidth}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\hspace{16pt}  Draw an equilateral triangle.

\textbf{Construction:}

\lipsum{4}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example behavior]

Comment: I discovered \WGclear which seems to help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285756/wrapfig-followed-by-a-list-items-after-the-first-does-not-wrap-around-correctly

Comment: There is a newer package that might work when `wrapfig` doesn't (I successfully used it for a document, though it has its own limitations as well), take a look at the `wrapstuff` package (documentation on CTAN is in Chinese, but an English version is in their GitHub as a PR: https://github.com/qinglee/wrapstuff/pull/12/files)

Comment: There are some versions of wrapfig and lipsum which don't get along.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a latex older than 2020-04-21 you get

[image]

`wrapfig` documents that the paragraph containing the wrapping text should not start in a group that ends before the cutout finishes. Otherwise wrapfig "forgets" where it is and re-starts the cutout.

Your example is like

```
{x}  Draw an equilateral triangle.
```

with the paragraph starting at `x` inside the group. You can fix this with

```
\leavevmode {x}  Draw an equilateral triangle.
```

so the paragraph starts before the `{`.

In your case, that would be

```
\leavevmode\hspace{16pt}  Draw an equilateral triangle.
```

Which produces the required output.

It is somewhat weird to start a paragraph with `\hspace` but I suspect this should be considered a latex bug, especially as it worked until 2020.

To see what changed see `ltspace.dtx` which has the old and new versions:

```
% \begin{macro}{\@hspace}
% \changes{LaTeX2e}{1993/08/05}
%    {(RmS) Removed superfluous \cs{leavevmode} in \cs{@hspace} and
%               \cs{@hspacer}, as suggested by CAR.}
% \changes{v1.3m}{2020/04/21}{Support calc syntax (gh/152)}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</2ekernel>
%<*2ekernel|latexrelease>
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{2020/10/01}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@hspace}{Support calc with \hspace}%
\def\@hspace#1{\begingroup\setlength\skip@{#1}\hskip\skip@\endgroup}
%</2ekernel|latexrelease>
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{0000/00/00}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@hspace}{Support calc with \hspace}%

%<latexrelease>
%<latexrelease>\def\@hspace#1{\hskip #1\relax}
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
```

A `\begingroup` group was added to support `calc` but we could probably adjust this.

Comment: If you (plural, meaning the team) just had never done that evil change in 1993 and removed the `\leavevmode` :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would you recommend to use instead of \hspace{16pt} to indent a single line?

Comment: @rhody `\hspace*` would be a bit more natural (and wrapfig would work:-)  but really any use of hspace in  document is suspicious. A font change such as `\textbf{Aim:}` followed by explicit spacing is the classic example of what latex's "logical markup" aims to avoid. It should be a list item or heading or custom command or something, with the layout implemented elsewhere. Of course using `\myfoo{Aim}` would make your document logically cleaner but wouldn't necessarily help fix your problem as this is basically a latex bug which we will fix....  So I'd just use `\hspace*` here...

Comment: I thought of using a list but felt it was overkill for just one line.

Comment: PS \hspace* works.

Comment: As an experiment, I tried using an enumerate list, but it added a large amount of white vertical space before and after the list which didn't look right. I know I can fix that but its too much code just to indent a single line. For now, I'll stick with hspace*